# Join com a mesma tabela mais de uma vez

Tags: mysql, sql-select

Estou com um problema ao realizar uma *query*.

A tabela original chama `tbl_operacao`, e contém os campos:
`id`, `tipo_operacao`, `idimovel`, `idproprietario`, `idlocatario`, `idseguro`, `idvalores`.

Quando eu chamo os valores do `idproprietario` e `idlocatario` os valores vem iguais.

```
SELECT 
  `tbl_operacao`.`id`,
  `tbl_operacao`.`tipo_operacao`,
  `tbl_imovel`.`descricao`,
  `tbl_endereco`.`endereco`,
  `tbl_endereco`.`num`,
  `tbl_endereco`.`bairro`,
  `tbl_pessoas`.`nome`,
  `tbl_pessoas`.`sobrenome`,
  `tbl_pessoas`.`nome` as 'nome2'
FROM
  `tbl_operacao`
JOIN `tbl_imovel` 
  ON (`tbl_operacao`.`idimovel` = `tbl_imovel`.`id`)
JOIN `tbl_endereco` 
  ON (`tbl_operacao`.`idimovel` = `tbl_imovel`.`id` AND `tbl_imovel`.`idendereco` = `tbl_endereco`.`id`)
JOIN `tbl_pessoas` 
  ON (`tbl_operacao`.`idproprietario` = `tbl_pessoas`.`id`)
JOIN `tbl_pessoas` as ps2 
  ON (`tbl_operacao`.`idlocatario` = ps2.`id`)
```

Vou precisar criar uma *stored procedure* ou uma *function* para conseguir os valores corretos?

Answer (score 3):

Sua *query* está meio confusa, demorou um pouco para eu entender o que você queria fazer, mas acho que é isso:

```
SELECT 
  `tbl_operacao`.`id`,
  `tbl_operacao`.`tipo_operacao`,
  `tbl_imovel`.`descricao`,
  `tbl_endereco`.`endereco`,
  `tbl_endereco`.`num`,
  `tbl_endereco`.`bairro`,
  pro.`nome`      AS proprietario_nome,
  pro.`sobrenome` AS proprietario_sobrenome,
  loc.`nome`      AS locatario_nome,
  loc.`sobrenome` AS locatario_sobrenome
FROM      `tbl_operacao`
LEFT JOIN `tbl_imovel`           ON `tbl_operacao`.`idimovel` = `tbl_imovel`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `tbl_endereco`         ON `tbl_imovel`.`idendereco` = `tbl_endereco`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `tbl_pessoas`  AS pro  ON `tbl_operacao`.`idproprietario` = pro.`id`
LEFT JOIN `tbl_pessoas`  AS loc  ON `tbl_operacao`.`idlocatario`    = loc.`id`
```

O problema da sua *query* original é que você pedia duas vezes a mesma coisa, só mudando o *alias* do campo retornado, em vez de definir os *aliases* da origem.

Comment: Muito obrigado, não sabia que dava para colocar as aliases na origem.

Comment: Então não tem problema de usar a mesma table se colocar um alias para identifica-las ?